# Запись рандомных чисел в progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Есть скрипты для того чтобы можно было записывать числа и вывести их в виде заполнения контейнера с водой. Как можно с интервалом в 5 секунд записывать рандомные числа?  Что не так с кодом для рандомного вывода чисел?

Вот сам код:

```
$(function () {
atualizaProgresso = function () {
    var percent = $('input[type=number]').val();
    var atual = $('.barra-progresso .concluido').data('p');
    percent = percent > 100 ? 100 : percent;
    mudaNumero(atual, percent);
    $('.barra-progresso .concluido').animate({
        height: percent + '%'
    }, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: "swing"
    });
    $('.barra-progresso .concluido').data('p', percent);
};
$('button').click(atualizaProgresso);
$('.barra-progresso .concluido').data('p', 0);
atualizaProgresso();
 });


  function mudaNumero(de, para) {
if (typeof timer1 == "number") {
    clearInterval(timer1);
}

decimo = (para - de) / 10;
para = parseInt(para, 10);
de = parseInt(de, 10);

vezes = 1;
timer1 = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (vezes == 10) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
    }
    de = de + parseFloat(decimo, 10);
    $('.barra-progresso .percentual .numero').html(Math.round(de));
    vezes++;
}, 30);
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
$(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
  });
```

И для рандомного ввода с интервалом в 3 секунды:

```
getRandomArbitrary = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

var timerId = setInterval(function() {
 let data = .concluido.data.( 0).data;
 data.forEach((num, index) => {
return data[index] = getRandomArbitrary(0, 100);;
 });
 .concluido.update(3000);
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: У вас синтаксические ошибки `.concluido.data.( 0).data` и `.concluido.update(3000);` и может где-то еще.

Comment: Это я уже понял , а вот где именно ,я поэтому и написал этот вопрос потому-что уже перепробовал варианты

Comment: Не могу помочь, т.к. не знаю, что такое `.concluido`. Похоже на какой-то элемент. Я бы вам посоветовал в начале хотя бы немного разобраться с js, css и html. А потом уже начинать что-то делать.

Comment: C css, html я разобрался , у меня этот проект уже почти готовый но вот рандом почему-то не выводится . Сейчас залью весь код ,может поможет ...

Comment: Если бы вы разобрались с css, html, то у вас бы такой проблемы не вознкло 100%. Вам похоже надо взять элемент `.concluido`, но вы этого не делаете, а делаете неизвестно что)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Универсальное решение задачи с записью в массив случайных чисел с задержкой

```
var arr=[];

function getRandNum(min, max) {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
var randNum = getRandNum(min, max);
arr.push(randNum);
timerId = setTimeout(tick, 5000);
}, 5000);
```